# How can I make my gradient background cover the whole div?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, background, gradient

I'm working on making a website better to read. I succeeded in covering my photos with background gradients to make the letters more visible. The problem is that the background gradient doesn't cover the entire div/image.

Here is the code:

```css
#us_grid_1 .usg_vwrapper_1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding-top: 5rem;
    padding-right: 2rem;
    padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;
}

    #us_grid_1 .usg_vwrapper_1 {
    background: linear-gradient( transparent, rgba(30,30,30,0.8));
}
```

```html
<style id="us_grid_1_css">@media (max-width:1023px){#us_grid_1 .w-grid-item{width:50%}#us_grid_1 .w-grid-item.size_2x1,#us_grid_1 .w-grid-item.size_2x2{width:100%}}@media (max-width:767px){#us_grid_1 .w-grid-item{width:50%}#us_grid_1 .w-grid-item.size_2x1,#us_grid_1 .w-grid-item.size_2x2{width:100%}}@media (max-width:599px){#us_grid_1 .w-grid-item{width:100%}}</style>
<div class="w-vwrapper usg_vwrapper_1 align_left valign_bottom bg_gradient "><h2 class="w-grid-item-elm usg_post_title_1 color_link_inherit with_text_color  post_title entry-title">Connections Panel</h2></div>
```

In this website: 
https://marketingsciences.nl/

Comment: what is `#us_grid_1` that in css??

Comment: The css do not apply to your code.

Comment: The css of #us_grid_1 gives the .usg_vwrapper a gradient background to cover it.

Comment: The css of the .usg_vwrapper_1 div appears in my code. I only wanted to show the relevant code in here. If I can clarify it by giving anything more let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `#us_grid_1` from css because you do not set in html `id=us_grid_1`

Learn about [selector in css](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

```css
 .usg_vwrapper_1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding-top: 5rem;
    padding-right: 2rem;
    padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;
}

.usg_vwrapper_1 {
    background: linear-gradient( transparent, rgba(30,30,30,0.8));
}
@media (max-width:1023px){
.w-grid-item{width:50%}
.w-grid-item.size_2x1,
.w-grid-item.size_2x2{width:100%}
}
@media (max-width:767px){
.w-grid-item{width:50%}
.w-grid-item.size_2x1,
.w-grid-item.size_2x2{width:100%}
}
@media (max-width:599px){
.w-grid-item{width:100%}}
```

```html
<div class="w-vwrapper usg_vwrapper_1 align_left valign_bottom bg_gradient"><h2 class="w-grid-item-elm usg_post_title_1 color_link_inherit with_text_color  post_title entry-title">Connections Panel</h2></div>
```

Comment: I found out that the #us_grid_1 id is an inline style element in the html. It makes sure the css properties you give only apply to that certain section. I added the code into my snippet.

Comment: but you do not have `#us_grid_1 ` id in HTML like this `<div id="us_grid_1"></div>`

Comment: In the snippets see the first line of HTML where I put <style id="us_grid_1_css">. That's the id where the css refers to.

Comment: So what ?? you must style in css according html tag (the fact you set id to `style` tag no help)

Comment: I really sorry about it but you have to learn css a little bit more

Comment: The way I put it in here works on my website. I can't however copy my whole website in here, therefore the link. As for my css skills, the reason i'm not that experienced is why I was aksing you for help.

Comment: set the media in css sheet and remove the `#us_grid_1`

Comment: happy to help :) and sorry about the `learn` issue(but honestly that the way we advanced in life)

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can follow this https://codepen.io/alexcarpenter/pen/LveDx  here image and  **gradient** both used combaundky

```css
#us_grid_1 .usg_vwrapper_1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding-top: 5rem;
    padding-right: 2rem;
    padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;
}
.bg_gradient {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(156, 106, 106, 0), #008464);
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<style id="us_grid_1_css">@media (max-width:1023px){#us_grid_1 .w-grid-item{width:50%}#us_grid_1 .w-grid-item.size_2x1,#us_grid_1 .w-grid-item.size_2x2{width:100%}}@media (max-width:767px){#us_grid_1 .w-grid-item{width:50%}#us_grid_1 .w-grid-item.size_2x1,#us_grid_1 .w-grid-item.size_2x2{width:100%}}@media (max-width:599px){#us_grid_1 .w-grid-item{width:100%}}</style>
<div class="w-vwrapper usg_vwrapper_1 align_left valign_bottom bg_gradient "><h2 class="w-grid-item-elm usg_post_title_1 color_link_inherit with_text_color  post_title entry-title">Connections Panel</h2></div>
```

Comment: Also very helpful. Thank you!